# Find location where process started from on linux

Tags: linux, process

If I have output from ps like the following, is there any way to determine where 'blah' is on the file system? For my particular situation, the -p specifies which port the application should run on.

```
user 22913 22470  0 09:58 ?        00:00:06 ./blah -p 12345
```

My question is basically whether or not it is possible to find the location of an executable given the PID or port of the application. The distro being used is Redhat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do any of these give information?

ps -ef

ps -eLf

ps axms

Or maybe

ps -o cmd= -p $PID

This might be more useful:

readlink -f /proc/$PID/exe

?

Comment: readlink just echoes back what the input is on the system I'm using. The other commands give me back the ./blah instead of the /abc/def/blah I'm looking for.

Comment: What do you mean by the input the system is using?
bsilver@desktop:~$ ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
29626 pts/3    00:00:00 bash
29644 pts/3    00:00:00 ps
bsilver@desktop:~$ readlink -f /proc/29626/exe
/bin/bash
bsilver@desktop:~$

Comment: Whoops didn't format that right...but it did show that ps was saying "bash" but readlink for that PID said /bin/bash is the executable path.

Comment: The command I used was "readlink -f /proc/29626/exe" to get that pathname.

Comment: Sorry. It was because the user I was logged on as didn't have permissions. readlink is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Like Bart suggested,

```
readlink -f /proc/$PID/exe
```

shoud give you your answer.

Answer (score 5):

To build on the readlink stuff, another way might be `readlink -f /proc/$PID/cwd`.  This will display the Current Working Directory of a process, which can be handy if you've executed a bash script, since the exe link is then /bin/bash, with an argument of ./blah.

And as a bit more random information, you can just cd to /proc/$PID.  There will be symlinks for cwd and exe, as mentioned, as well as where that processes root directory is (useful if chrooted)  `ls -l` will show where these are pointing, which is essentially what readlink is doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo /usr/sbin/lsof -p 22913
```